# Hotmail Sender ID always fails with "temperror" regardless of SPF

Tags: domain-name-system, authentication, spf, email

When we send mail to Hotmail servers, they do not recognize our Sender ID. In the receiving mail source, it reads

**Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=temperror ...**

when it should say pass as with every other one. Therefore our legitimate mails go to junk folder.

A few things to point:
- SPF is correctly done and works with every other big email providers such as Yahoo, Gmail etc.
- We submitted our Sender ID long time ago.
- We have signed up for JMR program.
- We have tried all of the steps above with another domain of ours and different IPs as well, nothing changed.

We have been getting this error for weeks. I wonder how people who have "pass" in the header do this.

I am aware that Sender ID is not the only thing affects deliverability, but I need to fix only Sender ID, as it seems to be hardest one to solve and probably this is the only problem we have. IP and domain are both new, and not on any blacklist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Seem to be a bug on hotmail side. 
I have same problem as you since 3 months, some domains with same spf records than other domains, are failing with senderid=temperror.

I have wrote to hotmail, they tell me it's a bug on their side (maybe on their dns cache), and they are working "actively" to resolv it ...

hotmail sucks ....

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue still exists (having the same issue with hotmail as we speak)

Comment: Does this issue really still exist? I'm having exactly the same issue: ALL other ESPs and checks work flawlessly, but hotmail insists on temperrors both for DKIM and for SPF.

Answer (score 3):

The OpenSPF people have an explaination for these temperrors.

From http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Hotmail_and_TempError :

> Hotmail does not use live DNS for Sender ID. They have a DNS cache
>   that they update twice per day. All TempError means is that your
>   domain's SPF record is not in their cache. To get your record added to
>   their cache, send an e-mail message to senderid@microsoft.com with
>   your domain in it. They will add it, but be patient as it's a manual
>   process and the cache only updates twice a day.

I'd express my opinion of the people responsible for this, but I'm pretty sure it'd violate the site guidelines on profanity.

Comment: The email address senderid@microsoft.com does not work anymore and all pages arelated to senderid have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the question should be, so I do assume: "How to check SPF records?"

Best guess is to visit http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html, fill out the form(s) and check for errors. You will probably see no errors, otherwise Google would reject it right away. But you may see warnings. Take care of warnings, fix them and you will see.

And then you should be aware that Sender ID **is not** SPF. See the Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID) and the [OpenSPF](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_vs_Sender_ID) website (when it'll be back online). But there are even more [resources](http://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/1695095/hotmail-delivery-tips-sender-id-spf).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SPF records have been set for a long time and functioning normally with all email providers. They all show pass, but the problem is that Hotmail does not pull them.

Comment: @Tom Do you have Sender ID records?!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a message to port25's verifier address `mailrcheck-auth@verifier.port25.com`.  You may want to review my experiences in [Detecting Email Server Forgery](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/detecting-email-server-forgery/).  The article includes a list of verification services which may help you track your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening with other ISPs. It is not an issue with your SPF. I believe due to new conformance measures there are changes in the reading of SPF and DKIM. I see this error more wit strict SPF settings but no DKIM. You do not need DKIM, but I think unfortunately there is some correlation to these errors and the missing DKIM.